# How to countDistinct on multiple columns

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

How can I, using the JPA criteria API do the following:

```
select count(distinct column1, column2) from table
```

Doing this on one column/path is simple using CriteriaBuilder.countDistinct, but how can I do this on two paths/columns?

Comment: note: some dbms do not support this kind of syntax. i don't know if any does. AFAIK Hibernate doe not support this

Comment: Indeed that seems to be the problem. MySQL does but probably not very common

Comment: did you find in the meantime any solution to your question? I am having the same situation and don't find a solution for it.

Comment: It seems there is no way to do this in JPA2

Comment: IN HQL you can do something like `select count(distinct a.column1)  from table table1 a left join a.tableb b group by b.column2, a.column1` but the `exceuteQuery` result needs to gather `.sum()` of results

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a late answer :-) though I'm not sure if things had changed.

Recently I encountered the very same need, and worked around it using concat, i.e., by concatenating the columns into a **pseudo column**, then `countDistinct` on the pseudo column.

But I couldn't use `criteriaBuilder.concat` because it generated JPQL using `||` for the concatenation, which [Hibernate had trouble with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469858/jpa-criterialbuilder-concat-force-to-use-concat-function).

Fortunately there's [`@Formula`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2785), thus, I mapped the pseudo column to a field with `@Formula`:

```java
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
  @Column(name="col_a")
  private String colA;

  @Column(name="col_b")
  private String colB;

  @Formula("concat(col_a, col_b)") // <= THE TRICK
  private String concated;
}
```

This way I can finally use the `concated` field for `CriteriaBuilder.countDistinct`:

```java
//...
Expression<?> exp = criteriaBuilder.countDistinct(entity.get("concated"));
criteriaQuery.select(exp);

TypedQuery<Long> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
return query.getSingleResult();
```

I wish JPA would (or hopefully already) support `countDistinct` with multiple columns, then all these mess could have been avoided.

Comment: Ah, yes that should work. Ugly hack but at least it works! :)

Comment: I actually solved it using a native query and it will likely perform better than your solution, but I can see how your solution will work as well.

Comment: I see, and yes, native query would definitely perform better, especially when considering how index would be used. My wish is still there and open.

Comment: I rather prefer the above SQL functionwith variable arguments since this is generic.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is no way to do this with JPA2

Answer (score 1):

You can use hibernate dialect for this task. To do this, create your own dialect, that extends dialect of DB what used ([list of all dialects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html)), and then register new function. For example, I use MySQL 5 with InnoDB engine:

```
public final class MyDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {
    public MyDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("pairCountDistinct", new SQLFunctionTemplate(LongType.INSTANCE, "count(distinct ?1, ?2)"));
    }
}
```

After then add new property in persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.example.dialect.MyDialect" />
```

And now you can use this function:

```
// some init actions
final CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Long> criteria = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
final Root<SomeEntity> root = criteria.from(SomeEntity.class);
criteria.select(builder.function("pairCountDistinct", Long.class, root.get(SomeEntity_.field1), root.get(SomeEntity_.field2)));
final long result = entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();
// some close actions
```

Comment: Nice idea and can be improved using `VarArgsSqlFunction` to be more flexible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462384/how-can-get-count-of-rows-in-hibernate-when-hql-have-group-by/69320916#69320916

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, build up an Expression consisting of all desired columns using the concat method, but then you can just pass that Expression to the countDistinct method.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<MyEntity> root = cb.from(MyEntity.class);
// build up an expression with multiple columns
Expression exp = root.get("column1");
exp = cb.concat(exp, root.get("column2");
exp = cb.concat(exp, root.get("column3");

cq.select(cb.contDistinct(exp));

var result = em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
var count = Math.toIntExact(result);
```