# JPA CriterialBuilder.concat force to use concat function

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, concatenation

I'm using `CriteriaBuilder.concat` to concatenate 2 Strings, using code below:

```java
Expression<String> concat = criteriaBuilder.concat(expr1, expr2)
```

But the generated SQL is something like:

```sql
select distinct col_1 || col_2
```

which causes `org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException`:

```
expecting CLOSE, found '||' near line 1, column 48 [
select count(distinct generatedAlias0.hostname || generatedAlias0.device) from ...
                                                ^(1,48)
```

I wonder how to force it to generate the following SQL which uses the `concat()` function, instead of the `||` operator?

```sql
select distinct concat(col_1, col_2)
```

#### Update:

From the error we can see that the problem is more on the Hibernate (`v3.6.10.Final`) side, which is why making MySQL to accept `||` for concatenation doesn't help, also updating to a newer version is not an option for me.

Thank you

Comment: Hibernate should translate the criteria to SQL using the appropriate dialect for your database. Maybe you've configured it to use the Oracle dialect instead of the MySQL dialect. Post your JPA/Hibernate configuration(s).

Comment: I checked the configuration, and I'm using [play1](https://github.com/playframework/play1), which use [driver specific dialect](https://github.com/playframework/play1/blob/a483edf09aedbe11cd087aa85e3fa91053f99516/framework/src/play/db/jpa/JPAPlugin.java#L306) by default, for MySQL, the dialect is a subclass of [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect](https://github.com/playframework/play1/blob/44230c118db7527127316adb054c5ad178f7092d/framework/src/play/db/jpa/MySQLDialect.java#L8).

Comment: ^ updating the links in above comment for the correct branch/version: [driver specific dialect](https://github.com/playframework/play1/blob/1.2.x/framework/src/play/db/jpa/JPAPlugin.java#L284), which extends [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect](https://github.com/playframework/play1/blob/1.2.x/framework/src/play/db/jpa/MySQLDialect.java#L8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've actually found a workaround. by using [`@Formula`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2785) (from Hibernate) instead of `CriteriaBuilder` for the same task, like this:

```java
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

  @Column(name="col_a")
  private String colA;

  @Column(name="col_b")
  private String colB;

  @Formula("concat(col_a, col_b)")
  private String concated;

  //...
}
```

This way I can use the `concated` field for `CriteriaBuilder.countDistinct`:

```java
//...

Expression<?> exp = criteriaBuilder.countDistinct(entity.get("concated"));
criteriaQuery.select(exp);

TypedQuery<Long> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
return query.getSingleResult();
```

I wish JPA would (or hopefully already) support `countDistinct` with multiple columns, then all these mess could have been avoided (see: [How to countDistinct on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184135/how-to-countdistinct-on-multiple-columns), the answer was **NO**).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with the concat function. 
I have used the concat function in a selectCase and this also returns the same QuerySyntaxException.

My workaround is to use the concat function via criteria builder function:

```
cb().selectCase().when(cb().equal(root.get(Person_.flag), cb().literal("1")), 
        cb().function("CONCAT", String.class, root.get(Person_.something), cb().literal(" bla bla bla")))
    .otherwise(root.get(Person_.something)))
```

Hibernate Version 4.3.11.Final

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well. The JPA/HQL generated sql query use `pipes as concat` (which is `||`).

- I am using Mariadb 10, Springboot-data-jpa2.0.6 (with Hibernate 5.2.17)

#### Issue example

- Given HQL: `select x from Xxx x where concat(x.field1, x.field2) = $1`
- Generated SQL: `select ..... where (x.field1 || x.field2) = ?`

#### Reason:

- Use of `||` is deprecated, since mysql 8.0, unless the PIPES_AS_CONCAT SQL mode is enabled: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html
- For mariadb: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/or/

#### Work around:

1. (preferred) ranther then use `concat` function, there is a similar one `concat_ws`: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/concat_ws/
2. Use JPA native query `@Query(nativeQuery = true, value ="select * from ....")`
3. `set global sql_mode=<list of modes which contains PIPES_AS_CONCAT>` 
   (I didn't try this)

Comment: Using native query is indeed a viable solution, thanks!