# Count the number of groups in HQL Query?

Tags: grails, hql

I have the following HQL query:

```
select c.device from Choice c 
group by c.device
```

Now I want to count the number of groups in the result not the number of devices per group.

I tried:

```
select count(distinct c.device) from Choice c 
    group by c.device
```

but this give the number of distinct devices in each group. This is something like `[2,3,4]`. But I need `2+3+4`.

**How do I get the number of groups with HQL?**

Comment: Looks like [sum](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html_single/#d5e2074) might do what you want?

Comment: Also, do you need a count of the groups, which based on your sample would be `3`, or do you need a sum of all the groups, which would be `9`?

Comment: No, definitively it is not sum.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184135/how-to-countdistinct-on-multiple-columns. Late in day but may help others -  a comment describing  HQL way. 
Some how we have ended up with two different queries based on grouping sum: this 
`SomeClass.executeQuery("select count(distinct subClass.someThing)  "+query+grpStmt,whereParams).sum()`
and this:
`SomeClass.executeQuery("select new map (mainClass.id as id)"+query+grpStmt,whereParams)?.size()`
They both produce the same identical result but happens the distinct lookup  `.sum()` is considerable faster than the latter `.size()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to do a count of a count, which is not supported in HQL.

## SQL

In SQL it would look something like this:

```
select count(innerQuery.counted)
from (select count(d.id) as counted
      from Choice c inner join Device d
      on c.device_id = d.id
      group by d.id) as innerQuery
```

In the example above the outer query selects from a sub-query which returns the groups. The outer query then does a count on the generated `counted` column.

## HQL

An alternative is to do a count and then get the size of the list.

```
Choice.executeQuery('select count(c.device) from Choice c group by c.device').size()
```

There's a performance penalty because the counting is done on the client-side.

Comment: I think instead of ``.size()`` you have to do ``.sum()``?

Comment: The `size()` would give you  _the number of groups_ because each record represents a single grouping. `sum()` would give you the total number of devices. For example, `assert [2,3,4].size() == 3` and `assert [2,3,4].sum() == 9`